# Tabulator: load data from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I want Tabulator to automatically load data from a JSON file.
I have made it work with a button.
I have read the q & a here
[Load table data from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806073/load-table-data-from-text-file)
I have also read the documentation here.
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/data#array-initial
(By the way, I was expecting the ajaxURL documentation to show a URL ending with a FILE name rather than "/now"... something like `$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");` )

I'm not a professional developer so please be gentle with me.

Here is the content of the JSON file (called "test_Array.txt" and in the same directory as the HTML).

```
[
{"name": "Oli Bob", "age": "12", "col": "red", "dob": "14/05/1982"},
{"name": "Mary May", "age": "1", "col": "blue", "dob": "14/05/1982"},
{"name": "Christine Lobowski", "age": "42", "col": "green", "dob": "22/05/1982"},
{"name": "Brendon Philips", "age": "125", "col": "orange", "dob": "01/08/1980"},
{"name": "Margret Marmajuke", "age": "16", "col": "yellow", "dob": "31/01/1999"}
]
```

It passes validation at
https://jsonlint.com/

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.1.3/dist/css/tabulator_site.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.1.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>tabulator3</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example-table"></div>

    <script>
        //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205, 
        // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        //layout:"fitDataFill",//fit columns to fit data and width of table (optional)
        //data:tableData, //set initial table data
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
                {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
                {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
            ]
        });
      
    //load sample data into the table
    table.setData("test_Array.txt")
    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off I would say you have posted a link to the v4.4 documentation, but using version 5.1 of Tabulator. It is defo worth reading the correct docs to get started :)

Following on from that the issue that you are experiencing is because as of version 5.0 Tabulator now has an async start up process that means you cant just call `setData` straight after instantiating the table, you must wait for the `tableBuilt` event:

```js
table.on("tableBuilt", function(){
    table.setData("./test_Array.txt");
});
```

More importantly if you are just loading data straight from the file then there is no need to set data after the table has been built, you can use the `ajaxURL` setup option to load the data into the table while it is being built:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"./test_Array.txt",
    ... other table options
});
```

As a complete aside if the text file just contains JSON data, then the convention is to end the file with `.json` instead of `.txt`

Comment: Hi Oli
Thank you for your detailed reply. 

Re: v4.4 docs: that was my cut/paste error. I had looked at the v5.1 docs which I interpreted as "use setData". I couldn't see a mention of "tablebuilt" under the "Loading Data" documentation v5.1.
I'm not a developer so I copy 'easy-to-follow" examples to try and learn. 

Re: .txt vs .json
Thanks. I had actually tried both but, as the other Stackflow question (in my first link above) had suceeded, I just copied that.
 
Everything now works.  I will post the complete result for any other novices.  
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For any other novices/amateurs out there....following Oli's advice I have a working solution as follows:

Create a JSON file called **text_Array.json** with the following content:

```
[
{"name": "Oli Bob", "age": "12", "col": "red", "dob": "14/05/1982"},
{"name": "Mary May", "age": "1", "col": "blue", "dob": "14/05/1982"},
{"name": "Christine Lobowski", "age": "42", "col": "green", "dob": "22/05/1982"},
{"name": "Brendon Philips", "age": "125", "col": "orange", "dob": "01/08/1980"},
{"name": "Margret Marmajuke", "age": "16", "col": "yellow", "dob": "31/01/1999"}
]
```

Create an html file called **tabulator3.html** with the following content.  Put the JSON file in the same folder as the HTML file and it will work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.1.3/dist/css/tabulator_site.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.1.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<!-- the line below is necessary for the Date sorter to work - it is buried in the v5.1 documentation here
http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/sort#func-builtin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>tabulator3</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example-table"></div>

    <script>
        //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        ajaxURL:"test_Array.json",        //load sample data into the table
        height:205, 

            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
                {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
                {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress"},
                {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
                {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
            ]
        });
      
   </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, Oli!